# eBay API - GetOrders - How to get Country Code?

Tags: ebay-api

How do I get the `CountryCode` (US, CA, etc.) from the results of a `GetOrders` API call?

Tried this, but it gives me: 224,116

```
Dim ShipInfo As AddressType = Order.ShippingAddress
Dim CountryCode As String = ShipInfo.Country
```

Tried this, but it gives me: United Stats, Canada, etc.

```
Dim ShipInfo As AddressType = Order.ShippingAddress
Dim CountryCode As String = ShipInfo.CountryName
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
Dim ShipInfo As AddressType = Order.ShippingAddress
Dim CountryCode As String = ShipInfo.Country.ToString()
```